# R: index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique (Zoo)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, zoo

I am pulling financial data in and trying to output it with shiny. I am not familiar with zoo functions. In attempt to make positive returns green, and negative returns, red, I am receiving the following error:

Warning in zoo(cd, order.by = index(x), ...) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(shiny)

#Stock assignments
stock_1<-'AMZN'
stock_2<-'CMG'
stock_3<-'TSS'  
stock_4<-'FB'
stock_5<-'T'

#Creating Input Boxes for Stocks and Weights of the Portfolio
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Portfolio Daily Returns'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(6,textInput("S1",h3('Input Stock 1'),stock_1)),
        column(6,numericInput("w1",h3("Input Weight 1"),.25))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,textInput("S2",h3('Input Stock 2'),stock_2)),
        column(6,numericInput("w2",h3("Input Weight 2"),.25))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,textInput("S3",h3('Input Stock 3'),stock_3)),
        column(6,numericInput("w3",h3("Input Weight 3"),.2))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,textInput("S4",h3('Input Stock 4'),stock_4)),
        column(6,numericInput("w4",h3("Input Weight 4"),.2))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(6,textInput("S5",h3('Input Stock 5'),stock_5)),
        column(6,numericInput("w5",h3("Input Weight 5"),.1))
      ),
      dateRangeInput("D",h3("Input Start and End Dates"),
                     '2019-09-01',Sys.Date())
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

#Shows daily volatility of your portfolio returns. Set for the last month but can adjust
server <- function(input,output){
  dataInput <- reactive({
    dat <- tq_get(c(input$S1,input$S2,input$S3,input$S4,input$S5),from=input$D[1],to=input$D[2])%>%
      group_by(symbol)%>%
      tq_transmute(select=volume,mutate_fun = periodReturn,period='daily',
                   col_rename = 'Daily_Vol')%>%
      tq_portfolio(assets_col=symbol,returns_col = Daily_Vol,weights=c(
        input$w1,input$w2,input$w3,input$w4,input$w5),col_rename = 'Port_Vol')
    dat$sign = ifelse(dat$Port_Vol >= 0, "positive", "negative")
    return(dat)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dataInput(),aes(x=date,y=Port_Vol))+geom_col()
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive"="green","negative"="red"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: To clarify, the problem is somewhere in the last two sections of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to get a graph with red and green bars.  First change the dat$sign assignment statement to match the following:

```
dat$sign = ifelse(dat$Port_Vol >= 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Then change the renderPlot statement to match the following:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  dat <- dataInput()
  ggplot(dat,aes(x=date,y=Port_Vol,fill=sign))+geom_col()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","green"))
})
```

I did not get a 'zoo' error when running the code, so I cannot help you with that issue.  You may want to make sure the zoo library is updated on your machine.